# Why are HTTP request and response objects in Node.js streams?

Tags: node.js, http

I'm trying to learn the basics of Node.js, and I have a fairly naive question about HTTP handling.  Here's a basic echo server, via [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/):

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var body = [];
  request.on('data', function(chunk) {
    body.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', function() {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    response.end(body);
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

If I didn't know anything about HTTP and I looked at this code, I would assume that it is some sort of streaming API: there is an input stream (`request`) and an output stream (`response`), and this particular server redirects the contents of the input stream into the output stream as data arrives.  This impression is reinforced by the fact that under the hood the `request` object implements the `ReadableStream` interface and `response` implements `WriteableStream`.

But this is not how one traditionally views HTTP!  The client issues a single discrete request and then waits for a single discrete response.  I'm not aware of any situation where the server must begin composing a response before the request is read in full, and the client cannot modify the request or directly influence the response once the request has been submitted.

So my question is:

> Why do Node.js `request` and `response` objects use streaming API's?  Is there any added flexibility or functionality which can be achieved by fully exploiting this fact?

Answer (score 1):

Network connections are inherently streams. HTTP requests and responses often are small enough to fit in a string, but both can also be extremely large or even infinitely large.

If request and response bodies are represented as strings, this means that it's just not possible to represent larger (or infinite sized) bodies.

Using a stream for this means that bodies of any length can be represented. Many frameworks provide some mechanism to convert these bodies to strings for easier access though.

Answer (score 0):

If you look only at the HTTP protocol, then there is one situation where the receiving part would process the data before everything is sent and that's for `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

Also if you look on HTTP form the browser side streamign still makes sense. e.g. for large jpegs browser can already start to display them if only parts are transmitted, you can start to listen to music before everything is sent to you, ...

For node, the reason is to prevent blocking and high memory usage or at least to allow to prevent that if the data can be processed as stream. If you request a large file that you want to save locally, then you don't want to keep the whole file in memory, and you don't want to block your code until you have written everything to the file. As soon as you got some data you want to write that to the disk. Or you if you have data that you can process line by line to save it in a database then there is also no need to wait for all data. ....